# How do I attach metadata to a text corpus with quanteda?

Tags: r, text, corpus, quanteda

I am using `quanteda` to create a text corpus and trying to attach metadata, but I keep getting an error. I have used this code before on another dataset, but for some reason it's not working with my current dataset. The code is:

```
dfm.ineq1 <- corpus(df.ineq$speech, 
                        docnames=df.ineq$speechID, 
                        docvars=select(party))
```

The error I get is:

> Error in select_(.data, .dots = lazyeval::lazy_dots(...)) :    object
>   'party' not found

I also tried to put party in quotes and got this error:

> Error in UseMethod("select_") :    no applicable method for 'select_'
>   applied to an object of class "character"

The party column is pretty straight forward. The values are:

```
"Democratic"  "Republican"  "N/A"         "Independent"
```

Any ideas on what might be going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized I forgot to put the dataframe in the select parenthesis!

```
dfm.ineq1 <- corpus(df.ineq$speech, 
                        docnames=df.ineq$speechID, 
                        docvars=select(df.ineq, party))
```

Answer (score 1):

An even easier way: use the fact that the `corpus` constructor method is defined for data.frame objects.

```
dfm.ineq1  <- corpus(df.ineq, text_field = "speech")
```

This will automatically load the text field in `speech` correctly, and include `speechID` and `party` as docvars.